# Requirements and effect of Export/Import lists and documents from one farm to another

Tags: powershell, administration, export, import

I want to export a list from one farm and import it inside another farm. using these commands:-

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://****/subsitename/" -ItemUrl "Sales" -Path "c:\export4.cmp"

Import-SPWeb http://site –Path "c:\temp\export4.cmp"
```

now i am not sure if i can still do this operation while i have the following:-

1. both farms are on-premises sharepoint 2013. but have different build numbers. one farm have this build number "15.0.4569.1000", while the other have this build number "15.0.4875.1000"??
2. now the site i want to export the list from is a sub-site of type team site and the same case apply to the sub-site i want to import the list to. and both sub-sites have the publishing feature disabled. but inside the source site collection (which contain the sub-site containing the list) it have the publishing feature enabled at the site collection level only. while on the destination site collection (which contain the sub-site containing the list) the publishing feature is enabled on the site collection level and also on the site level (root site).. but again the sub-sites which contain the list on the source and destination have the publishing feature disabled

so can i still do the export/import for the document library while having the above 2 points exists in my case ?

second question. now i want to export the list from live and import it inside another test farm.. so if the import fails, what could be the consequences on both farms?or nothing serious ? could this for example cause the farm which i am importing the list to to get upgraded or downgraded as a result that both farms have different build numbers?? or this is not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Import and export operation required both farm should be same SharePoint version i.e. 2010 to 2010. But you can go lower build to higher build number within same SharePoint version.
2. Both site collection should have same level of features. As you importing it subsite of then it should be fine as both root site having publishing features.

Import & export operation will not effect the farm configuration etc. but possibility you may be orphan list in your destination site collection which you have to delete...this is in case of failure.
I am sure import will fail as it is from different version.

Comment: thanks for the info... so the export/import need the same requirements as for backup/restore... so now in my case i want to copy the documents from the source farm into the destination farm.. and i want to preserve the documents properties such as created,modified,created-by and modified-by... so is there a way to do so? now the source farm have 20 docuemnt libraries.. and i have created 20 empty documents libraries inside the destination farm.. now the issue i am facing is how to copy the documents from the source to the destination? do u have any idea?

Comment: now if i manually copy/paste the documents the created date and created by will be equal to the user who perform the operation and the date the operation was performed.....and not the original values..

Comment: now i tried to export a document library from our live server using this command `Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://****/Marketing/" -ItemUrl "Shared Documents" -Path "c:\export4.cmp" -CompressionSize 1000 -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity -Force –Verbose` and it generates a single file of 185 MB size.. then inside our test farm i run this command to import the list `Import-SPWeb http://t*****/sites/ccc/n/ –Path "c:\export4.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity –Verbose`

Comment: and i found that i was able to copy the original documents (550 docs) and preserving the docs properties such as modified,created,modifiedby and created by.... so now i am asking my self since i am doing the export/import operations on 2 farms which have different farm build numbers.. so could this operation be risky? or since the import completed successfully then i should be fine ?

Comment: If it works for you then why worried because once it imported with all the properties then it's done.

Comment: now sometimes in sharepoint there are some operations which might work but it is unsupported... so my worry if doing an export/import on 2 different farms which have differetn farm build numbers is a supported or unsupported operation ?

Comment: I was confused. You should be fine as to u are going from lower build to higher build but within same SharePoint version. That's why you are successful. It is supported operation as you did not change anything manually i.e. updating the content db or change in the bakup files.

Comment: @Wasqas yes i did not change any thing manual... but if we take as an example the backup/restore for a site collection then this operation is not supported even if i backup a lower version farm, and i restore it inside a higher version farm.. but seems in the export/import world  things are more flexible ...is this correct?